# How to replace the Hexadecimal values to its original character string in C?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I have correlated the Token value taken from the following response snippet:

```
result.sessionToken = '7AFF3BA8\x2DD913\x2D4211\x2D990E\x2D7DF3AB5687B7';
```

Using the web_reg_save_param function as:

```
web_reg_save_param(
"TOKEN",
"LB=result.sessionToken = '",
"RB=';",
"ORD=1",LAST);
```

But in a later request I need to send the correlated value in the below format:

```
7AFF3BA8-DD913-4211-990E-7DF3AB5687B7
```

The value `\x2D` is to be substituted by `-`.

I am right now using the below 'C' and LR code for this:

```
strcat(pstr1,lr_eval_string("{RToken}"));
strcat(aSeparator,"\\");

for(a=0,b=0;pstr1[a]!=NULL;a++,b++)
{
    if(pstr1[a]==aSeparator[0])
    {
        strcat(pstr2,"-");
        pstr2[b+1]=pstr1[a+4];
        a=a+5;
        b=b+2;
    }
    pstr2[b]=pstr1[a];
}   

lr_save_string(lr_eval_string(pstr2), "sessionToken");
```

I wanted a generic and another approach for this problem. I don't want to use `web_convert_param` function, but if there is a hidden trick to convert the string as desired I would like to know.

Thanks,
Ritika

Answer (score 0):

Try This...**lr_save_string(lr_eval_string("{TOKEN}"),"convertedtkn");**